# Compare two Lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have three lists, BeforeList, AfterList and FinalList

BeforeList has the following values

```
ID Description Operation
1  Descr1      Null
2  Descr2      Null
3  Descr3      Null
```

AfterList has the following values

```
ID Description Operation
1  Descr1      Null
2  DescrC      Null
4  Descr4      Null
```

My FinalList would be

```
ID Description Operation
1  Descr1      Null
2  DescrC      Update
3  Descr3      Delete
4  Descr4      Add
```

How do I get the FinalList using LINQ

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what is the relationship between the BeforeList and AfterList. Is there a key on ID?

Comment: And why would *DescrC* be `Update` but *Descr1* be `null`?

Comment: The relationship between both the List is ID.

Comment: I'm interested in how you get Op=Update or Delete? and... what happened to Descr2 and why?

Comment: Descr2 updated to DescrC by the user and the new Descr4 added by the user, Descr3 deleted by the user

Comment: It would be a little cumbersome to do with Linq. I would just do a helper method and use normal for/foreach loops to make things cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
var beforeListById = beforeList.ToDictionary(item => item.Id); 
var afterListById = afterList.ToDictionary(item => item.Id); 

var finalResult = from id in beforeListById.Keys.Union(afterListById.Keys)

                  let before = beforeListById.ContainsKey(id) ? beforeListById[id] : null
                  let after = afterListById.ContainsKey(id) ? afterListById[id] : null

                  select new Record
                  {
                      Id = id,
                      Description = (after ?? before).Description,
                      Operation = (before != null && after != null) 
                                   ? (after.Description == before.Description ? "Null" : "Update")
                                   : (after != null) ? "Add" : "Delete"
                  };
```

**EDIT**: Made query simpler (assuming items are non-null).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple implementation, but you could try something like this:

```
var differences = listA.Where(a => !listB.Any(b => b.id == a.id)).Union(listB.Where(b => !listA.Any(a => a.id == b.id)));
```

**EDIT**

According to MSDN, you can just use `Union` to merge the two lists, and duplicates will be filtered out by default. If not, you can always call `Distinct()`:

```
List<Something> = beforeList.Union(afterList).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need distinct union on your lists. Here there was a discussion about unions which could give an example of a syntax: [Linq to entities : Unions + Distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296966/linq-to-entities-unions-distinct)